# Addressing registers with I2C STM32F0 HAL libraries

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, stm32, stm32f0, hal-library

I'm very new to using STM's CUBE and HAL_libraries. I'm using an STM32F0 microcontroller with 32 pins. The schematic for I2C is correct.
So I need a little help here.

I have a capacitive sensor ([FDC1004](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/fdc1004.pdf)) that uses I2C communication.  I have to write these registers to read the data.

How could I correctly send START request form master to slave (slave address is A0)?

How to set pointer to 0x0C register?

- Datasheet sees (Register 0x0C:bit[7:4]) to 1.) I don't know, how to do that? And finally how to READ from the same register?
- Plus I have to wait DONE_x field (Register 0x0C:bits[3:0]) before I read it?

But I don't know if I am addressing the right registers! Because I don't get any data back from the sensor!

Here is my code:

```
int I2Ccomm ()
{

    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1,0xA1,0x0C, 10, 100); //start bit and pointer to register
    HAL_Delay(50);
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1,0xA1,0x054, 10, 100); // setting the register
    HAL_Delay(50);

    HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, 0xA0, 0x0C, 10, 100); //read from this register
    HAL_Delay(50);
    HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, 0xA0, 0x02, 10, 100); //read data from register

    return ReadREG[1];
}
```

Comment: Please ask a more specific question(s). like How do I address X register properly? This is a badly worded question. For further guidelines see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Then is it better to write a new question or just edit this one?

Comment: Better to edit, less questions and we won't have to close this one.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let's start with the `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit()` function. If you check its declaration:

```
 HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint16_t DevAddress, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout);
```

1. Minor problem with **2nd** parameter, the slave device address. The slave device address is `b1010000` if we complete it to 8bit format, it will be `0xA0`, just as you said. Now when passing this to `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit()` you do not have to set the R/W bit manually, HAL will do it for you. So when you call `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit()` the transmitted R/W bit will be automatically **0 indicating write operation** and when you call `HAL_I2C_Master_Receive()` the the transmitted R/W bit will be automatically **1 indicating write operation**. You have mixed the R/W values but I think it is a don't care bit for the function, so it is not an actual error in your code.
2. The **3rd** parameter (`uint8_t *pData`) is a **pointer to a buffer** which contains the **data to be sent**. Now, in your call the **3rd** parameter is `0x0C` which is your actual data, the register address. The problem is, it will be interpreted as a pointer (by the `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit()`) to a memory location, where some undefined data can be found.
3. The **4th** parameter is the **size of the buffer**, the number of bytes to be sent. If you want to send a **single** byte then this parameter should be **1** and not 10.

When working with \$ \small I^2C \$ the best thing to do is to get the datasheet of the slave device and look up the documentation of write and read operations.

### Write registers

Here is the corresponding diagram from the datasheet.

[image]

So after sending the slave address to the bus, three more bytes should be transmitted: **register pointer**, **MSB byte**, **LSB byte**. A general implementation with HAL writing 16bit registers:

```
void write_register(uint8_t register_pointer, uint16_t register_value)
{
    uint8_t data[3];

    data[0] = register_pointer;     // 0x0C in your example
    data[1] = register_value>>8;    // MSB byte of 16bit data
    data[2] = register_value;       // LSB byte of 16bit data

    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, 0xA0, data, 3, 100);  // data is the start pointer of our array
}
```

Example with your values: `write_register(0x0C, 0x0054);`

Alternatively HAL defined register write function can be used as well, which has additional parameters for passing register address and address size.

```
void write_register(uint8_t register_pointer, uint16_t register_value)
{
    HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_OK;

    status = HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, 0xA0, (uint16_t)register_pointer, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, (uint8_t*)(&register_value), 2, 100); 

    /* Check the communication status */
    if(status != HAL_OK)
    {
        // Error handling, for example re-initialization of the I2C peripheral
    }
}
```

---

Now, the `HAL_I2C_Master_Receive()` function is almost the same as the other.

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint16_t DevAddress, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout);
```

Only difference is that the **3rd** parameter is a pointer to the buffer where the **received data** will be stored. It is `0x02` in your code and I do not know what was your purpose with it, but it will be interpreted as a pointer (unfortunately to a random memory location).

### Read registers

[image]

To read a register, it must be selected with an \$ \small I^2C \$ write operation by sending the appropriate register pointer (Note that if you have written this register right before the read then you do not have to send again its address to the pointer register, as you have already set it during write). Then with an \$ \small I^2C \$ read operation, read back the 16bit data.

```
void read_register(uint8_t register_pointer, uint8_t* receive_buffer)
{
    // first set the register pointer to the register wanted to be read
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, 0xA0, &register_pointer, 1, 100);  // note the & operator which gives us the address of the register_pointer variable

    // receive the 2 x 8bit data into the receive buffer
    HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, 0xA0, receive_buffer, 2, 100);   
}
```

Example:

```
uint8_t reg_ptr = 0x0C;
uint8_t buffer[2];

read_register(reg_ptr, buffer);

// the register content available in the buffer
```

There is also a HAL defined register read function as well, which has.

```
uint16_t read_register(uint8_t register_pointer)
{
    HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_OK;
    uint16_t return_value = 0;

    status = HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, 0xA0, (uint16_t)register_pointer, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, &return_value, 2, 100);

    /* Check the communication status */
    if(status != HAL_OK)
    {

    }

    return return_value;
}
```

---

Read through *8.5 Programming* section of the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/fdc1004.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now it is finally working.
But one more question? 
Do I have to wait a few mili secundes for reading or could I read without any delay?

Comment: I do not think that any delay is necessary, you could try without any first.

Comment: You do not need to wait, I2C involves looping on the clock signal until the slave has completed.

Comment: In case anybody else has my issue,  7bit device address must be shifted left 1 bit. ie my target was `0x60`, but used `0xC0` on `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read`