# Interfacing touch sensor with stm32f7

Tags: stm32, c, i2c, touchscreen

I'm having that touch sensor ST IC ST1633i. 
It's integrated into an LCD. I'm trying to interface with it, but don't know or understand the actual protocol.

Here is the protocol

[image]

[image]

So I'm trying to write multiple data as shown

as shown in the figure, I have to write a start header 0xaa, then the data register that I plan to read which is 0x12.

```
status = HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(i2c_handler, 0xaa, 0x12, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, 0x01, 1, 1000);
```

Then I read

```
 nbTouch = TS_IO_Read_Multiple(0xab, 0x12, buf[0], 1);
  nbTouch = TS_IO_Read_Multiple(0xab, 0x12, buf[1], 1);
  nbTouch = TS_IO_Read_Multiple(0xab, 0x12, buf[2], 1);
```

In all cases Read and for Mem_Write it gives me HAL_ERROR with ACKF error
I'm using I2C1.

```
#define DISCOVERY_I2Cx_TIMING                      ((uint32_t)0x40912732)
```

Comment: Kinda strange how a public datasheet says, "CONFIDENTIAL". It's almost like they're giving the entire internet an NDA... Okay back to your question. Here's a [related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/244491/addressing-registers-with-i2c-stm32f0-hal-libraries) to what you're asking

Comment: @KingDuken Did I write the functions calls correctly ? I mean it's very confusing. 0xaa as start header, and the register I want to read from is 0x12 ?

Comment: Have you probed your I2C bus from your master to slave? Usually a NACK (or how you said ACKF) indicates that there's some improper address to that slave.

Comment: Very funny, in my documentation for the ST1633i the default touch device address is 0x55, but by using this address, it failed with HAL_ERROR with ACKF. As soon as I tried your address 0xAA, it worked. So I would assume you are using the wrong touch device address